# compute depth map from corresponding

Tags: opencv

I have 2 stereo images, fundamental matrix, corresponding between two images for each pixel (almost).

Is there an OpenCV function (even if it is in extra module) that helps me getting the normalized depth map based on the previous information?

Comment: [This](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html)?

Comment: @Miki Thanks.. This works from images.. I have done most of the work.. I have the corresponding  (matched pairs) between the images. I just want some function that does the math and computes the depth map

Comment: I know that was too easy ;) I don't know, sorry. But [dispartyMapFormation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/246ea8f3bdf174a2aad6216c2601e3a93bf75c29/modules/stereo/include/opencv2/stereo/matching.hpp#L569) seems a good start